# OS to heightmap

Tags: qgis, convert

The USGS site is easy to use, with .adf files opening directly in QGIS 3 and saving to a .png

Our UK OS site allows easy downloading too, but now the files downloaded are geotiffs which show surface maps as in Maps. I know the point-heights are in there grr...

QGIS is very impressive - but how to convert the Ordnance Survey tifs to heightmaps in QGIS please?

Comment: The tif (which you've not given us a link to) is a heightmap, isn't it? Have you got a raster of heights? A digital elevation model?

Comment: Look at the panorama data set which is a DEM

Comment: OS Terrain 50 is new version of panorama (discontinued 31 March 2017) https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html#OPMPLC in shape, ascii, gml formats (1.1GB)

Comment: OS Open Map - Local

Data type: Raster

Supply format: GeoTIFF Full Colour

Comment: ...is the dataset. I thought that this type of file contains .elevation data, and that I can extract the height data from it. Panorama data set, thanks will investigate

Comment: OS Open Map (Raster) tiffs are image files of the cartographic maps. Even if it had contour lines and spot-heights (which I don't think it does) getting that data out of the image is like extracting data from a photograph.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the data you are using does not contain elevation data. If you are looking at a large area you can use [OS Terrain 50](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html) or if you are looking at a small area you can try [LiDAR data](https://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/index.jsp#/survey). The OS data has a larger cell size so its not as accurate but will work for larger areas. Whereas the LiDAR data has more accuracy but will be very slow for large study areas.

Comment: Note that one OS Terrain 50 DEM covering all of GB is now available as a GeoTiff (as a trial). Free from here, the very last item. http://data-format-trial-osonline.opendata.arcgis.com/pages/os-terrain-50